# Porque o array_shift é considerado uma função lentissima?

Tags: php, array, desempenho

De acordo com o Manual, `array_shift` remove o primeiro elemento do array.

Já vi muitas críticas pela internet a fora a respeito da performasse dessa função, pelo fato da mesma reordenar todo o índice do array a cada remoção, realocando assim todo o array.

Achei esse gráfico que representa a diferença de performasse entre `array_shift` e `array_pop`(remove o último elemento do array), que mostra uma diferença absurda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já vi alterativas, como o exemplo abaixo, para evitar o "problema de desempenho" (por causa da reindexação dos índces) da seguinte forma:

```
function array_first(&$array)
{
   reset($array);

   $key = key($array);

   $value = $array[$key];

   unset($array[$key]);


    return $value;
}
```

- Criar uma alterativa "manual" realmente é a melhor forma de resolver esse problema?
- O que faz essa função ser lenta é simplesmente a reindexação dos elementos, ou existem também outros fatores?

Comment: A função que você colocou me parece ser o comportamento de `array_pop`, não de `array_shift`...

Comment: Corrigido @Oeslei

Comment: Considero que se você tiver um array com 1000 posições, o problema está na implementação e abaixo disso o `array_pop` está com desempenho similar conforme o gráfico. Ainda assim, se você não precisa da reordenação dos índices, a função que você colocou seria uma alternativa melhor ao `array_shift`.

Comment: Já está com `reset`, amigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A performance desta função é lenta em determinadas ocasiões devido a reindexação que é feita para reordenar os itens do *array*, tem que ser levando em consideração que sua complexidade é [O(n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions).

Supondo que tenhamos um *array* com *5* valores e quiséssemos retirar o primeiro elemento do *array* com a função [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), o processo seria algo assim:

```
array     >>  a b c d e f
copia     >> [a]
deleta    >> [a]
array     >>  " b c d e f
reindexa  >>  " b c d e f
                ↙ ↙ ↙ ↙
array     >>  b c d e f
```

O funcionamento interno de [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) é *basicamente* assim:

- Obtém o primeiro valor, onde [`arData`](http://phpcrossref.com/xref/glossword/_variables/index.html#arData) é um *array* usado para definir os valores da *array* recebida:

  ```
  >> idx = 0
  >> while(1)
  >>   p = Z_ARRVAL_P(stack)->arData + idx;
  >>   val = &p->val;
  ```
- Copia esse valor para devolver como retorno:

  ```
  >> ZVAL_COPY(return_value, val);
  ```
- Depois de copiado o valor, ele é eliminado:

  ```
  >> if (Z_ARRVAL_P(stack) == &EG(symbol_table).ht) // <-- se for Hashtable
       zend_delete_global_variable(p->key)
  >> else
       zend_hash_del(Z_ARRVAL_P(stack), p->key)
  ```
- Agora é feito a *reindexação* dos itens:

  ```
  >> if (Z_ARRVAL_P(stack)->u.flags & HASH_FLAG_PACKED) { // <-- Se for array compactada
  >>   uint32_t k = 0;
  >>   for (idx = 0; idx < Z_ARRVAL_P(stack)->nNumUsed; idx++) 
  >>      p = Z_ARRVAL_P(stack)->arData + idx;
  >>      if (Z_TYPE(p->val) == IS_UNDEF) continue; // <-- Se não existir valor, continua
          if (idx != k) // <-- Se for diferente de 0, 0: item já não existente
              Bucket *q = Z_ARRVAL_P(stack)->arData + k;
              q->h = k;
              q->key = NULL;
              ZVAL_COPY_VALUE(&q->val, &p->val);
              ZVAL_UNDEF(&p->val);
          }
          k++;
      }
  ```
- Esse processo de reindexação pode não entrar no bloco de código acima caso a *array* não tenha a *flag* `HASH_FLAG_PACKED` (indica que é um *array* compactado) e pode entrar no bloco de código do `else` na linha [2246](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fc33f52d8c25997dd0711de3e07d0dc260a18c11/ext/standard/array.c#L2236).

Utilizar ou não essa função pode depender do tamanho da *array* a ser analisada, existem alternativas como usar a função [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-pop.php) em conjunto com [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php) ou [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.reset.php) com [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-pop.php) ou [`unset($array[$indice])`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php), está última **talvez** não seja tão lento quanto `array_shift`.

Answer (score 1):

A função se torna lenta justamente reindexação dos elementos, no seu gráfico mesmo fica bem claro que quanto maior o número de elementos no array maior o tempo de execução.

E ao meu ver não há nenhum problema em contornar isso com alguma outra alternativa, como implementar sua própria função.

---

Se você quiser analisar segue o código da implementação das funções no PHP
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fc33f52d8c25997dd0711de3e07d0dc260a18c11/ext/standard/array.c

Na linha [2167](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fc33f52d8c25997dd0711de3e07d0dc260a18c11/ext/standard/array.c#L2167) tem a implementação do **array_shift** e na linha [2106](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fc33f52d8c25997dd0711de3e07d0dc260a18c11/ext/standard/array.c#L2106) a do **array_pop**, ambas são similares apenas notando o fato da reindexação dos elementos do array na função array_shift, como esta descrito na linha [2218](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fc33f52d8c25997dd0711de3e07d0dc260a18c11/ext/standard/array.c#L2218)

Answer (score 1):

> Criar uma alterativa "manual" realmente é a melhor forma de resolver
>   esse problema?

A função `array_shift` tem um tempo de execução de 2<sup>n</sup>, ou seja, quanto maior for o *array*, mais tempo irá demorar. Isso só é um problema se você for trabalhar com *arrays* **muito grandes**.

De acordo com o *Benchmark*, até um tamanho de 1000 o desempenho é praticamente o mesmo que o `array_pop`.

> O que faz essa função ser lenta é simplesmente a reindexação dos
>   elementos, ou existem também outros fatores?

A função em si não é lenta. O fator que causa a lentidão é a carga de dados que ela tem para trabalhar. Refazer a função com uma implementação genérica pode ter o efeito contrário com *arrays* pequenos, pois as funções do núcleo são mais rápidas que funções do usuário.

Será bem difícil encontrar um caso específico que sempre a função vai receber uma carga gigante de dados. Se for esse o caso e as chaves do *array* não sejam relevantes, use uma implementação alternativa **somente** nesse trecho de código.

Um outra alternativa ao [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-shift.php) pode ser alcançada com a combinação do [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-pop.php) com [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php):

```
<?php

$array = array_reverse(getArrayGigante());

array_pop($array);
```